# How can I detect if a serviceworker install fails?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My serviceworker is partially generated by gulp, so there's some chance it ends up with a SyntaxError or TypeError if I've made a mistake, and I'd like to be about to detect in my `navigator.serviceWorker.register` code that this has occurred, and send an error report.

I haven't figured out how to do this. I figured there'd be some sort of "on fail" event but I haven't found one. It looks like maybe I'm looking for an SW with a `redundant` state...

I tried

```
const newWorker = reg.installing
newWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
  if (newWorker.state == 'redundant') {
    // log error
  }
})
```

but the condition doesn't seem to fire. This condition also doesn't fire:

```
reg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
  if (reg.redundant) {
    // log error
  }
})
```

I don't see any examples in the SW tutorials of this, which is surprising since it seems like a sort of basic thing to want to notice and detect.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a syntax error, or if your service worker contains anything that is invalid JavaScript, your call to `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` will reject. (It might also reject if there's a network error preventing the script from being downloaded.)

If your service worker contains valid JavaScript but throws a runtime exception prior to finishing the `install` step, then the service worker will transition from the `installing` state to `redundant`. Note that in this scenario, `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` will not reject, as the `redundant` state transition happens after the registration has succeeded.

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then((reg) => {
    // reg.installing may or may not be set, depending on whether
    // a new SW was registered.
    reg.installing?.addEventListener('statechange', (event) => {\
      if (event.target.state === 'redundant') {
        // There was a runtime error.
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('SW registration failed:', err));
```